# Complicated nested UL navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to turn a three level UL into an easy to use navigation system.

My idea is to have the first UL and it's LI's showing, but hiding the UL UL and UL UL UL, along with their respective LI's.

I'd like someone to be able to click on the top an LI, and then show the UL within that LI.

The idea then is that the parent UL hides, along with it's LI's, but NOT the sub UL I just selected.

If then another LI is clicked, it shows that LI's child UL and it's respective LI's.

The effect would be just one UL shown at any one time.

I understand this is complex, and I cannot fathom how this would be done - I'm guessing a combination of CSS and jQuery and I have tried various things and searched a hell of a lot hence I'm resorting to this.

If anyone has any ideas on what I'm talking about and how to implement it that would be great,as I'm a bit lost on where to even start.

---

EDIT

I wil have the UL within a fixed width div, so I could use overflow:hidden and negative values on the unused UL's to do "faux hiding".

Comment: A `ul/li` structure would not work with this layout because you would be unable to display a child `ul` as it's parent is hidden.

Comment: Yep, true! What I should have added was that this will be in a fixed size div with over flow hidden, so we can negatively position the unused UL's to make it look like it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little mock-up I've done in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6wSg/), you just need to go for some unorthodox workarounds to make this happen.

And yes, you will need some jQuery to make it happen, I made it with hover just for the example, you can use the events you need, this is just the principal:

```
$('.subdropdown').hover(
    function() { $(this).parent().parent().css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
    $(this).css({'visibility': 'visible'});},
    function() { $(this).parent().parent().css({'visibility': 'visible'});}
);​
```

Hope this helps.